# Не могу поймать исключение ShellExecuteEx

Tags: delphi

Была и есть у меня библиотека, только с некоторых пор у меня стала через раз работать функция «ShellExecute» (раз, 2, 3 откроет word файл, и все, далее программа файл создает, но не открывает (файл word – корректный, к тому же создает один и тот же файл по одному алгоритму)),
Заменил ее на «ShellExecuteEx»

```
function LAUNCH_FILE(const AFileName: string): Boolean;
var
  ShellExecuteInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  LExtension: PAnsiChar;
begin
  begin
    FillChar(ShellExecuteInfo, SizeOf(ShellExecuteInfo), 0);
    ShellExecuteInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME;
    ShellExecuteInfo.nShow := SW_MAXIMIZE;
    ShellExecuteInfo.lpClass := PChar(AFileName);

    ShellExecuteInfo.Wnd := FMain.Handle;

    ShellExecuteInfo.lpVerb := 'open';
    ShellExecuteInfo.lpFile := PChar(AFileName);
    ShellExecuteInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(ShellExecuteInfo);
    if not ShellExecuteEx(@ShellExecuteInfo)  then
    begin
       ShowMessage('bad');
         Application.MessageBox(PChar(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)), 'Ошибка', MB_OK or MB_ICONERROR);
      case ShellExecuteInfo.hInstApp of
        SE_ERR_FNF: ShowMessage('Файл не найден');
        SE_ERR_PNF: ShowMessage('Путь не найден');
        SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED: ShowMessage('Доступ к файлу запрещен');
        SE_ERR_OOM: ShowMessage('He хватает памяти');
        SE_ERR_DLLNOTFOUND: ShowMessage('Не найдена необходимая DLL');
        SE_ERR_SHARE: ShowMessage( '-Файл занят другим пользователем');
        SE_ERR_ASSOCINCOMPLETE: ShowMessage('Не полная информация о связанном с файлом приложении');
        SE_ERR_DDETIMEOUT: ShowMessage('Истекло время на выполнение операции DDE');
        SE_ERR_DDEFAIL: ShowMessage('Ошибочная операция DDE');
        SE_ERR_DDEBUSY: ShowMessage('Операция DDE занята');
        SE_ERR_NOASSOC: ShowMessage('Нет приложения, связанного с файлом');
      end

    end
    else ShowMessage('All right');
  end;
end;
```

Та же самая фигня, но теперь, даже если файл и не открывает, всеравно выдает мое сообщение «('All right')»., т.е. она вообще в блок «исключений» не входит.
Не открывает на Windows XP.
Delphi 10.2 у меня Windows 10.

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Попробуйте рекомендации в этой статье от GunSmokera https://www.gunsmoker.ru/2015/01/avoid-using-ShellExecuteEx.html

Comment: та я ж на эту статью и ориентировался

Comment: Если очень хочется именно ShellExecute, то посмотрите как происходит проверка кода ошибки в статье и у Вас. Но я бы перевел это на CreateProcess. К сожалению, воспроизвести поведение программы как у Вас у меня не получилось.

Comment: С чем ассоциировано на вашем компьютере расширение doc (или docx - смотря что за файл)? Что показывает ProcessExplorer - появляется ли после выполнения ShellExecute у вашего процесса какой-либо дочерний процесс?

Answer (score 0):

кажется нашел проблему: у меня функция сохраняющий документ

```
function SaveDocAs(ANamePath, ANameFile: string; AOpenDoc: integer):boolean; export;
//save created doc
{
LOpenDoc
  0 - not open created doc
  1 - open created doc
}
var
  LPath: string;
begin
  SaveDocAs := true;
  try
    begin
      Words_Templs.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ANamePath+VERIFICATION_NAME_FILE(ANameFile));
      CloseDoc;
      Close_Document(0);
      Words_Templs := Unassigned;
      CoUninitialize;
      if AOpenDoc = 1 then
        OPEN_MAKE_DOC(ANamePath, VERIFICATION_NAME_FILE(ANameFile), '', 0, LPath);

    end;
  except
    SaveDocAs := false;
  end;
end;
```

строки разрушаюшие объект

```
  Words_Templs := Unassigned;
  CoUninitialize;
```

были после "*if AOpenDoc = 1 then*", которые его открывают.
т.е. пытался открыть не разрушенный объект

только 10 это как-то обрабатывала, а ХР - отказывалась
Во всяком случае после этой замены, все пока открывается без проблем

Comment: странный код. Крайне странный. Непарный вызов CoUninitialize, неясные методы CloseDoc и CloseDocument, какая-то глобальная переменная Words_Templs, которая не здесь создается, но почему-то здесь уничтожается (хотя метод - явно не финализирующий)... Воздержусь от оценки, но фраза "Во всяком случае после этой замены, все пока открывается без проблем" говорит о том, что суть проблемы так и осталась непонятной.